# How to get existence of a temporary table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT * INTO #nima FROM Region r
```

Every time  I execute this queries:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nima')) 
--or
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('#nima'))
```

I get NULL, but when I execute above select I get error that #nima alreadty exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just using the [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function to determine if the temp table exists:

```
SELECT object_id('tempdb..#nima')
```

Or if you wish to retrieve the object name, you will need to specify the database id using the [DB_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx) function for the temp database:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nima'), DB_ID('tempdb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the internal id of #nima as expected in tempdb

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nima'))
```

OBJECT_NAME takes a local database ID. There will be no object (except by rare chance) with that ID locally because the ID comes from tempdb

Demo (untested!)

```
USE tempdb
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nima'))  --#nima + system generated stuff
USE MyDB
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nima'))  --null
-- Now we add DBID for tempdb
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#nima'), 2) -- #nima + system generated stuff
```